# How would I load the network adapters to test the PerformanceMonitor API?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, load-testing

I have a class which wraps various calls to `PerformanceMonitor` regarding the Network Interface statistics. I have run my tests while manually copying a large file to a shared drive to test calls which calculate the video on demand bandwidth, utilization, etc. Clearly not ideal.

How can I automate this or is there some sort of tool/emulator which hits the network card so that I can run my tests under load so that the correct values are produced?

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't sound like a unit test to me. Normally things like databases and bits of hardware would be mocked/faked/stubbed in a unit test, and 'fake' results supplied.

I'm afraid its difficult to be more specific with the given information, but in your case I would be looking for a way to provide a fake PerfMon API, which returns hard coded values. There's no value in testing the PerfMon API itself, so create a fake implementation and use that to test whether your code does the right thing in response to those values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Okay, I have mocked out the performance API but in the actual implementation I am doing some calculations that use several  performance counters that make one calculation. In order to see the output I need to flood the network to get some readings.